# select2 combobox with existing options

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox, jquery-select2

[`select2`](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) seems to be pretty much just what I need.  However, based on their documentation and [this example that I found](http://jsfiddle.net/seck4/100/), I can't figure out how to use a combobox with existing options.  If you look at the example (I updated this by adding some options to the `choices` array) you will see that the throbber on the select just spins and doesn't find any existing options at all.  However, it still allows you to input an option that is not already there, which is also what I need.

What do I need to do to update my usage of `chosen` so that you get all of the normal functionality like displaying options and typeahead/autocomplete, but also allowing users to add choices that don't already exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been having the same problem, but your post helped me figure it out. You have to put your existing options in the "choices" variable as JSON. So it should look like this:

```
var choices = [
{ id: 1, text: "foo" },
{ id: 2, text: "bar" },
{ id: 3, text: "Baz" }
];
```

You'll also need to add an ID to each one so that the selector will assign a value to each selection.

I'm trying to use an ajax call to get my options from a DB, so I have a bit more work to do. But if you're using static options, hopefully this will help.

Answer (score 2):

That's simple, you need to remember that **selects do accept pair data**: *id (value)* and *text (label)*. You have to provide such data. So I modified the `choices` variable.

Also I made a few other improvements like deaccented comparison, prepending new choices at the beginning and most important: fully matching terms won't create new duplicate choices.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/seck4/116/